# Group by Column Process Each Row

Tags: r

I am trying to process a grouping that has the same elements in column A, in the example below it'd create 3 groups from 0, 1, and 2. If the grouping has a value of "E" then use the value in column C from that row to create a new column "D" in every other row by subtracting it from the other values in column C from the grouping.

```
  A   B   C
------------------
  0   E   2
  0   F   4
  0   G   8
  1   E   10
  1   H   4
  2   J   3
```

Becomes:

```
  A   B   C   D
------------------
  0   E   2   NA    # Don't subtract from self
  0   F   4   2     # (4 - 2)
  0   G   8   6     # (8 - 2) 
  1   E   10  NA    # Don't subtract from self
  1   H   4   -6    # (4 - 10)
  2   J   3   NA    # no row with matching Column A and Column B == "E"
```

So for the rows with Column A equal to 0, it would subtract column C by 2 as the row with Column B equal to "E" or Column C is 2. The row with column A equal to 2 would not have a value as no rows in that grouping have a column B equal to "E".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 dat%>%group_by(A)%>%
     mutate(D=ifelse(length(C[B=="E"])>0,C[B=="E"],NA),
            D=replace(C-D,B=="E",NA))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   A [3]
      A     B     C     D
  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1     0     E     2    NA
2     0     F     4     2
3     0     G     8     6
4     1     E    10    NA
5     1     H     4    -6
6     2     J     3    NA
```

This can be written as:

```
dat%>%group_by(A)%>%mutate(D=ifelse(length(a<-C[B=="E"])>0,a,NA),D=C-`is.na<-`(D,B=="E"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`, it's fairly straightforward:

```
dat[, D := C - C[B == "E"], by=A][B == "E", D := NA][]

#   A B  C  D
#1: 0 E  2 NA
#2: 0 F  4  2
#3: 0 G  8  6
#4: 1 E 10 NA
#5: 1 H  4 -6
#6: 2 J  3 NA
```

Where `dat` was:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- read.table(text="  A   B   C
  0   E   2
  0   F   4
  0   G   8
  1   E   10
  1   H   4
  2   J   3", header=TRUE)

setDT(dat)
```